# How to get effect similar to nested alignes

Tags: align, split

I'm trying to align several equations.

[image]

In each equation, I would like to separate the condition part into two lines, i.e.,

[image]

As such, I use `align` and `split`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
&\inf_{y\in Y} (c(x, y) - \psi(y)) \\
= &\inf_{y\in Y} \inf \bigg \{ \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} ( c(x_{i+1}, y_i) - c(x_{i}, y_i)) : 
\begin{split}
        &n \in \mathbb N \\
        &(x_i, y_i)_{i=1}^n \subset S, y_{n} = y 
\end{split}
\bigg \} \\
= &\inf_{y\in Y} \inf \bigg \{ \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} ( c(x_{i+1}, y_i) - c(x_{i}, y_i)) : 
\begin{split}
        &n \in \mathbb N \\
        &(x_i, y_i)_{i=1}^n \subset S, y_{n} = y 
\end{split}
\bigg \}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

However, there is a big space between `:` and the condition part. Could you explain how to reduce such space? Thank you so much!

**Update:** I have tried using `align` instead of `split`, but Tex returns an error `Argument of \align has an extra }.`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{align}
&\inf_{y\in Y} (c(x, y) - \psi(y)) \\
= &\inf_{y\in Y} \inf \bigg \{ \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} ( c(x_{i+1}, y_i) - c(x_{i}, y_i)) : 
\begin{align}
        & n \in \mathbb N \\
        & (x_i, y_i)_{i=1}^n \subset S, y_{n} = y 
\end{align}
\bigg \} \\
= &\inf_{y\in Y} \inf \bigg \{ \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} ( c(x_{i+1}, y_i) - c(x_{i}, y_i)) : 
\begin{align}
        & n \in \mathbb N \\
        & (x_i, y_i)_{i=1}^n \subset S, y_{n} = y 
\end{align}
\bigg \}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please extend your example to a full minimal example.

Comment: I would not use `split` here but rather `aligned` (it is very seldom I feel the need to use `split`)

Comment: Your example stops at `! Undefined control sequence. <argument> ...i)) : \begin {split} &n \in \mathbb ` Please ensure the output you show is generated by the code you post

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I'm using Bakoma, so maybe the program can bypass some errors that I can not recognize...

Comment: No check your log, you can not get ℕ from the document posted

Comment: you can not nest `align`, daleif suggested `aligned` which is the form for a subterm of a larger display

Comment: @DavidCarlisle You are right! It should be `aligned` instead of `split`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See, if the following solution using `nccmath` and `mathtools` packages and considered comments below your questions, gives what you after:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nccmath, 
            mathtools, 
            amssymb}

\begin{document}
    \begin{align}
   \MoveEqLeft  % <---
\inf_{y\in Y} (c(x, y) - \psi(y))   \notag  \\
    & = \inf_{y\in Y} \inf \bigg\{ \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \bigl( c(x_{i+1}, y_i) - c(x_{i}, y_i)\bigr) :
\quad\medmath{\begin{aligned} % <---
        & n \in \mathbb N \\
        & \bigl(x_i, y_i\bigr)_{i=1}^n \subset S, y_{n} = y
    \end{aligned}}
\bigg\} \\
%
    & = \inf_{y\in Y} \inf \bigg\{ \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \bigl( c(x_{i+1}, y_i) - c(x_{i}, y_i)\bigr) :
\quad\medmath{\begin{aligned} % <---
        & n \in \mathbb N \\
        & \bigl(x_i, y_i\bigr)_{i=1}^n \subset S, y_{n} = y
    \end{aligned}}
\bigg\}
    \end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]